# Sql Server 2008 remote access problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access

I have problem with connecting to Sql Server from my local machine.

Seems like I did everything I could, but still I'm unable to connect to it.

This is what I did:

1) Right click on Sql Server in Sql Management Studio (SMS) -> Connections -> Allow remote connections

2) Right click on Sql Server in Sql Management Studio (SMS) -> Security -> Allow remote connections -> Set Auth mode to Win and Sql auth mode (i.e. mixed mode)

3) Disabled firewall

4) Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Network Configuration -> Protocols -> Enable Shared memory, Named pipes, TCP/IP

5) Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Network Configuration -> Protocols -> TCP/IP -> Properties -> Set TCP Port to 1433, Set TCP Dynamic  Port to 0. After that I restarted MainSql service in "services.msc"

6) I ran "EXEC xp_readerrorlog 1" in SMS, found this:

Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].
Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].
Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [  \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MAINSQL ].
Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [  \.\pipe\MSSQL$MAINSQL\sql\query ].
Server is listening on [ ::1  64825].
Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1  64825].

7) Tried to telnet [myip] 1433 from my home machine. Result: connecting To [myip]...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433
 : Connect failed

8) Tried to telnet [myip] 1433 from server - it worked!

Seems like this is some kind of a network issue. I have another server with Sql Server installed, I did the same on it and I was able to connect to it from my home machine, but not this one! I tried to connect to this server from the second one and it didn't work too.

Please help me, I don't know what to do. I did everything I could but it still doesn't work.

**Update:**
Sql Server Browser service is started on the server machine. The server is a dedicated server at a hosting, I'm trying to connect to it from my home machine and from another server witch is a dedicated server as well, from another country.

Comment: Is your server and home machine on the same subnet? if not, are there any routing/firewall issues between them?

Comment: No, server is not and the same subnet as home machine. Well, I'm not sure about how to troubleshout such issues. Server has IIS and I can interact with the web-sites on it

Comment: How do you connect to the Server, what subnet is it on, and what subnet are you on ? Do you connect through VPN? (I think you might be connecting to the wrong addresses, based on what's available for use for you)

Comment: I use RDP to connect to the server. And there is Sql Management Studio installed on it. I use it to configure the server and its databases. I don't use VPN to connect the server, all communications are though internet. BTW, should I? What I want to do - I have a dedicated server from one hosting company and I have another dedicated server from another hosting company. They are not related to each other. I want the second server to connect the first one's SQL DB

Comment: What i'm saying is that since this is on different hosting centers, there's probably firewall rules applying here, and especially blocking external access to SQL Server port. If you can VPN to the hosting center where you want to connect to the SQL DB - then try to connect, and this works, the problem is the firewall between.

Comment: So there might be an external firewall (not on my server, because I desabled it) which blocks connections on some ports? Thank you for the tip, I'll try to set up VPN and also I'll try to configure server to listen another port

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the port to 52 but I couldn't connect. The hoster said he doesn't block any ports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was in firewall. To fix it I ran a script from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968872

This **is** really strange because I fully disabled server's firewall. However it now works for me, thanks to cairnz and Gregory A Beamer for help.

Comment: Indeed! I was in the same boat. It wasn't my first rodeo, but dang what gives. Instead of running the whole kit and kabootle of the script in the referenced url, I just needed to run this one: netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer". In my case, I had already created this rule, or thought I did. I just deleted my rule and ran this, and bingo!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you hit one of two most likely causes: You have set protocols. Just double check the client side to ensure the same protocols are enabled on both sides and you are done there.

The second most likely, with SQL 2005 on, is the Browser service is turned off on the server. If this is true, you will often have issues with remote calls, ala http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277.

Comment: I foggot to mention about SQL Server Browser service - it is started. And I have the same protocols enabled on my home machine: Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP

Comment: Set up profiler on the server and see if the handshake is even attempted.

Comment: Thank you for a tip. I ran SQL Profiler, set up a filter for "test" login. When I connected to to database from server's SQL MS, profiler showed the login action, but when I tried to connect from my home computer's SQL MS, it showed nothing. Is there a way to check such connectivity problems?

Comment: The Browser service is only required for multiple instances. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @cairnz: ONLY required for? That is patently false. Yes, SSRP had a problem with instances, but that is not the only reason SQL Browser was created. SQL Browser also handles remote connections. It is turned off, by default (on install), to better secure the machine. Need proof? Read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277, especially the line that states to get remote connections working you "Turn on the SQL Server Browser service". And, yes, I have had people succesfully get remote working by simply turning on SQL Browser.

Comment: Your answer says "not accept anything but local calls" - which is wrong. Therefore, you only -need- it if you need to translate incoming connection requests to multiple instances - security aside. SQL Server Browser not running will still accept calls on default port to the defualt instance - ref: "If the SQL Server Browser service is not running, you can still connect to SQL Server if you provide the correct port number or named pipe. For example, you can connect to the default instance of SQL Server with TCP/IP if it is running on port 1433."

Comment: @cairnz: Okay, edited to reflect the offending part. And yes, there are ways around getting to SQL with Browser turned off, but the average Joe asking questions on this forum is unlikely to know the minutia of connecting to SQL Server than how to code around drag and drop FUD in a dataset or LINQ to SQL dbml, so it is often easier to short circuit.